# How to get value from upcomming row if condition is met?

Tags: r

I searched in google and SO but could not find any answer to my question.

I try to get a value from the first upcomming row if the condition is met.

Example:

```
Pupil   participation   bonus
  2           55          6
  2           33          3
  2           88          9
  2            0          -100 
  2           44          4
  2           66          7
  2            0          -33
```

to

```
Pupil   participation   bonus   bonusAtNoParti   sumBonusTillParticipation=0
  2           55          6          -94                    6+3+9 = 18
  2           33          3          -97                      3+9 = 12
  2           88          9          -91                       9
  2            0          -100        0                        0
  2           44          4          -29                     4+7=11 
  2           66          7          -26                       7
  2            0          -33         0                        0
```

So I need to do this:
Iterate through the dataframe and check next rows till participation equals to 0 and get the bonus from that line and add the bonus from the current line and write it to bonusAtNoPati.

My problem here is the "check next rows till participation equals to 0 and get the bonus from that line"
I know how to Iterate through the whole list but not after the current point(row)
I would need to do this process to the whole list where i can get any random participation value in random order.

Has anyone any idea how to realize it?

Edit, I also added another column("sumBonusTillParticipation=0", only sum value is required) which is even harder to realize. R is such a hard to learn language =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `which` to get which row number `participation` is 0.

```
df <- read.table(text = 'Pupil   participation   bonus
             2           55          6
             2           33          3
             2           88          9
             2            0          -100 
             2           44          4
             2           66          7
             2            0          -33', header = T)

index <- c(0, which(df$participation == 0))
diffs <- diff(index)
df$tp <- rep(df$bonus[index], times = diffs)
df$bonusAtNoParti <- df$bonus + df$tp
df$bonusAtNoParti[index] <- 0
df$tp <- NULL

     Pupil participation bonus bonusAtNoParti
 1     2            55     6            -94
 2     2            33     3            -97
 3     2            88     9            -91
 4     2             0  -100              0
 5     2            44     4            -29
 6     2            66     7            -26
 7     2             0   -33              0
```

Comment: What's wrong with this answer OP? It seems to reproduce your desired output. I don't fully get the comment above. If this answer doesn't work for some case, please show such case editing your question.

Comment: Hey nicola, myincas just edited his answer, do not worry =)

Comment: @fReezMA You should give a feedback. If this answer helped you, please upvote or accept it (or both). At least, you should say whether it solved your issue or not. People here are giving part of their time for you and the community, and you at least should give some feedback.

Comment: I think I asked a wrong question but your code seem to work. I upvote and accept it so other people with the same problem can solve it by using your guidance. Thank you